# regular expression what's the meaning of this regular expression s#^.*/##s

Tags: regex, perl

what is the meaning of `s#^.*/##s`
because i know that in the pattern `'.'` denotes that it can represent random letter except the `\n`.

then `'.*` 'should represent the random quantity number of random letter .

but in the book it said that this would be delete all the unix type of path.

My question is that, does it means I could substitute random quantity number of random letter by space?

Comment: Here is a [really decent tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) on regular expressions.

Comment: There is nothing "random" about any of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitutions conventionally use the `/` character as a delimiter (`s/this/that/`), but you can use other punctuation characters if it's more convenient. In this case, `#` is used because the regexp itself contains a `/` character; if `/` were used as the delimiter, any `/` in the pattern would have to be escaped as `\/`. (`#` is not the character I would have chosen, but it's perfectly valid.)

`^` matches the beginning of the string (or line; see below)

`.*/` matches any sequence of characters up to and including a `/` character. Since `*` is *greedy*, it will match all characters up to an including the *last* `/` character; any precedng `/` characters are "eaten" by the `.*`. (The final `/` is not, because if `.*` matched all `/` characters the final `/` would fail to match.)

The trailing `s` modifier treats the string as a single line, i.e., causes `.` to match any character including a newline. See the `m` and `s` modifiers in [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information.

So this:

```
s#^.*/##s
```

replaces everything from the beginning of the string (`$_` in this case, since that's the default) up to the last `/` character by nothing.

If there are no `/` characters in `$_`, the match fails and the substitution does nothing.

This might be used to replace all directory components of an absolute or relative path name, for example changing `/home/username/dir/file.txt` to `file.txt`.

Answer (score 5):

```
s      -> subsitution
#      -> pattern delimiter
^.*    -> all chars 0 or more times from the begining
/      -> literal /
##     -> replace by nothing (2 delimiters)
s      -> single line mode ( the dot can match newline)
```

Comment: "all chars 0 or more times from the begining" is an awful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It will delete all characters, including line breaks because of the `s` modifier, in a string until the last slash included.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse a little pedantry. But I keep seeing this and I think it's important to get it right.

`s#^.*/##s` is not a regular expression.

`^.*` is a regular expression.

`s///` is the substitution operator.

The substitution operator takes two arguments. The first is a regular expression. The second is a replacement string.

The substitution operator (like many other quote-like operators in Perl) allows you you change the delimiter character that you use.

So `s###` is also a substitution operator (just using `#` instead of `/`).

`s#^.*/##` means "find the text that matches the regular expression `^.*/` and replace it with an empty string. And the `s` on the end is a option which changes the regex so that the `.` matches "\n" as well as all other characters.